Algorithmic construction of a homogeneous polynomial written as a sum of powers of linear forms
I am a material physicist and in my research fiels of continuum plasticity, I am currently facing a problem that is very similar to this thread  and is as follows: I have a homogeneous polynomial of degree d and number of variables n=5. Degree d can be up to 20. I would like to express the polynomial as a sum of d-powers of s linear forms.
Is this always possible?
Is there a algorithmic way to do this? A symbolic math as Maple, sympy or Mathematica?
I tried to read several papers on Alexander-Hirschowitz problem, but I struggle to understand the terminology and the proofs. My apologies if you already answered these questions but if anybody could explain this to a non-mathematician I would appreciate it very much!
Tomas
